# Composite component and CSS

Tags: html, css, jsf

I have `newcss.css`

```
#formdiv {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 150 auto;

}
```

and composite component

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
    <composite:interface>
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
             <h:form id="formdiv">
                 ...
             </h:form>
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

When i'm trying to use this component in `index.xhtml` i cant observe any effects of `CSS` applying.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:lpform="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/mycomp"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <form>
        <mycomp:comp/>
    </form>
</html>
```

I need that my composite component lay at the center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is the composite component itself is setting a prefix to your form's id. If you use your `h:form` directly in your main page, you'll see the form id value is `formdiv` at client side (and consecuently properly acquiring its style).

However, when you use a composite, JSF stablishes an id for the composite itself, so for your form you'll have `j_idtx:formdiv`. The easiest way to go is **to use style classes instead of css selectors**:

```css
.formdivClass {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 150px auto;
}
```

```xml
<composite:implementation>
   <h:form styleClass="formdivClass">
     ...
   </h:form>
</composite:implementation>
```

**See also:**

- [What's the generated prefix j_idt33 in JSF component id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279189/whats-the-generated-prefix-j-idt33-in-jsf-component-id)
- [How to use JSF generated HTML element ID with colon ":" in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-in-css-selectors)

Comment: It doesnt work. I dont understand, why. For what <h:outputStyleSheet/> is needed?

Comment: Remove the output style sheet tag from your composite and let it only in your main page. It's required for jsf to know which css files to include.

Comment: Also about [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300578/css-style-doesnt-work-with-composite-component), don't post twice the same topic. Your questions will be marked as duplicated and removed. It's better to edit the same question adding new content, in order to get it relevanced again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you set an invalid value for the margin property, so the browser ignores it. You have to specify the unit on the numeric value, unless it is zero. So in this case you could fix it this way (if you want 150 pixels of top and bottom margin):

```
#formdiv {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 150px auto;
}
```

Comment: This was an error for sure, but there could be some other elsewhere. Could you please provide the URL of the actual page, or at least its code (as given to the client)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300578/css-style-doesnt-work-with-composite-component